# Code efficiency in Scala loops, counting up or counting down?

Tags: scala, performance, loops, numbers

Clearly, if you need to count up, count up. If you need to count down, count down. However, other things being equal, is one faster than the other? 
Here is my Scala code for a well-known puzzle - checking if a number is divisible by 13. 
In the first example, I reverse my array and count upwards in the subsequent for-loop. In the second example I leave the array alone and do a decrementing for-loop. On the surface, the second example looks faster. Unfortunately, on the site where I run the code, it always times out.

```
 // works every time
object Thirteen {
import scala.annotation.tailrec

  @tailrec
  def thirt(n: Long): Long = {
    val getNum = (n: Int) => Array(1, 10, 9, 12, 3, 4)(n % 6)
    val ni  = n.toString.split("").reverse.map(_.toInt)
    var s: Long = 0
    for (i <- 0 to ni.length-1) {
        s += ni(i) * getNum(i)
    }
    if (s == n) s else thirt(s)
  }
}

// times out every time 
object Thirteen {
import scala.annotation.tailrec

  @tailrec
  def thirt(n: Long): Long = {
    val getNum = (n: Int) => Array(1, 10, 9, 12, 3, 4)(n % 6)
    val ni  = n.toString.split("").map(_.toInt)
    var s: Long = 0
    for (i <- ni.length-1 to 0 by -1) {
        s = s + ni(i) * getNum(i)
    }
    if (s == n) s else thirt(s)
  }
}
```

I ask the following questions:

1. Is there an obvious rule I am unaware of?
2. What is an easy way to test two code versions for performance – reliably measuring  performance in the JVM appears difficult.
3. Does it help to look at the underlying byte code?
4. Is there a better piece of code solving
   the same problem, If so, I'd be very grateful to see it.

Whilst I've seen similar questions, I can't find a definitive answer.

Comment: I don't know if this would be any faster, but the code would be cleaner: `val s :Long = ni.indices.foldLeft(0L){case (acc,x) => acc + ni(x)*getNum(x)}`

Comment: I agree, much cleaner and runs successfully. Thank you.

Comment: The best tool that I'm aware of for benchmarking _Scala_ code performance (in terms of _CPU_ and memory overhead) is _[ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io/)_. It allows warm-up periods before collecting data (to account for _JIT_ performance improvements) and discarding of results due to _GC_ cycles, etc.

Comment: When I run your code on `130`, I see `i` bouncing forever at 0 and 1. With another println, it is recursing on `13` and `31`. So it's the algorithm, not the control structure or the Range.

Comment: I see the problem - a descending index is not enough. Many thanks for pointing that out, som-snytt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd be tempted to tackle it.

```
val nums :Stream[Int] = 1 #:: 10 #:: 9 #:: 12 #:: 3 #:: 4 #:: nums

def thirt(n :Long) :Long = {
  val s :Long = Stream.iterate(n)(_ / 10)
                      .takeWhile(_ > 0)
                      .zip(nums)
                      .foldLeft(0L){case (sum, (i, num)) => sum + i%10 * num}
  if (s == n) s else thirt(s)
}
```